# Drag and Drop outlook contacts using WinApi C++

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag an Outlook contact and to drop it into my app. The app is written in C++ using WinAPI (no MFC or .NET)

I am able to drag and drop files using `DragAcceptFiles()` and `WM_DROPFILES`, yet that solution does not work for Outlook contacts or emails.

Comment: DragAcceptFiles and WM_DROPFILES are for files, but you're not dragging a file. You need to register as an OLE drop target.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, so basically I cannot do it using only "plain" WinAPI? BTW, great blog:)

Comment: `RegisterDragDrop` is part of Win32.

Answer (score 0):

Does Outlook allow its contacts to be dragged/dropped within the application? Have you seen this done before with other apps? Doing this would involve getting a handle to the instance of Outlook, and then to the container holding the contacts, which you may not be able to access due to the fact that Outlook is a different process.

Comment: yes @rem45acp you can drag contacts from Outlook to, for example, Word or Notepad++. You'll get a table containing name, email, phone number ....